# Scala type classes with constructor dependency injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, typeclass

I'm trying to figure out how to get traditional constructor-based dependency injection to work with type class patterns.

For example, given

```
trait MyTypeClass[A] {
  def doSomething(a: A): Unit
}

class TypeClasses(prefix: String) {

  implicit val stringTC = new MyTypeClass[String] {
    def doSomething(a: String) = println(s"$prefix a")
  }

  implicit val intTc = new MyTypeClass[Int] {
    def doSomething(a: Int) = println(s"s$prefix $a")
  }
}

class MyLogic {

  def doSomething[A](a: A)(implicit myTypeClass: MyTypeClass[A]) = myTypeClass.doSomething(a)

  doSomething("Hello world")
}
```

What would be the best way to get the implicit type class instances inside an instance of `TypeClasses` into `MyLogic`?

The only things I've come up with are to either
a) Inject an instance of `TypeClasses` into `MyLogic` in the constructor, and then `import instanceOfTypeClasses._`. However this has the downside that it has to be repeated every class, and subclasses can't inherit the import.
or b) make `TypeClasses` a trait, `prefix` a def, and have `MyLogic` extend `TypeClasses` and then dependency inject an instance for `prefix` in the constructor. However this becomes messy as it's allowing the dependencies for `TypeClasses` to bleed into `MyLogic`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need *dependency injection*, as I may assume from your tags, you may try to use [distage](https://izumi.7mind.io/latest/release/doc/distage/index.html) ([slides](https://github.com/7mind/slides/blob/master/04-distage/target/distage.pdf)) DI framework for Scala (disclaimer: I'm the author).

It supports typeclass instance injection.

Because your typeclass instances are created dynamically in the TypeClasses class,
you have to add a `TypeClasses` constructor parameter in every class that needs
to call a function that requires a typeclass instance.
But, you can remove the `import typeclasses._` boilerplate by creating implicit
defs that would extract the instances from the TypeClasses object when it's available as an implicit:

```
trait MyTypeClass[A] {
  def doSomething(a: A): Unit
}

object MyTypeClass {
  implicit def intFromTypeClasses(implicit typeClasses: TypeClasses): MyTypeClass[Int] = typeClasses.intTc
  implicit def stringFromTypeClasses(implicit typeClasses: TypeClasses): MyTypeClass[String] = typeClasses.stringTC
}
```

Because the implicit defs are defined in the companion object for MyTypeClass they will always be available without any imports.

Then you should add `TypeClasses` as an implicit parameter in MyLogic, this would make it available for implicit defs to extract instances from:

```
class MyLogic(implicit typeClasses: TypeClasses) {

  def doSomething[A](a: A)(implicit myTypeClass: MyTypeClass[A]) = myTypeClass.doSomething(a)

  doSomething("Hello world")
  // same as doSomething("Hello world")(MyTypeClass.stringFromTypeClasses(typeClasses))
}
```

Then, in `distage`, declare the following bindings

```
import distage._

class MyAppModule extends ModuleDef {
  make[String].from("myprefix")
  make[TypeClasses]
  make[MyLogic]
}
```

And everything is wired:

```
val ctx: Locator = Injector().produce(new MyAppModule)

implicit val typeClasses = ctx.get[TypeClasses]
ctx.get[MyLogic].doSomething("Hello world")
```